# How do you use the rspec have_selector method to verify XML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rspec

I want to do some basic checking to ensure that an XML sitemap is being produced correctly but `have_selector` doesn't seem to be able to detect tags:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SitemapController do

  render_views

  before(:all) do
    # code to generate factory data
    # ...
  end

  # illustrating the problem
  it "should be able detect nodes that are definitely present" do
    get :index
    response.should have_selector('url')
  end
end
```

Every time I run the test I get the following error:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected css "url" to return something
```

The sitemap is being produced and when I debug the RSpec test and look at the `response` object I can see xml content:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > response.body
 => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">\n  <url>\n    <loc>http://test.host/panel ...
```

My sitemap is produced by the SitemapController and the view is located in `views/sitemap/index.builder.xml`.

Why isn't have_selector kicking in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybara doesn't support XML responses. It always uses `Nokogiri::HTML` to parse the content, which produces unexpected results when given XML.

Adding XML support has [been requested](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/524) but was rejected by Capybara's maintainer.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks John. Do you know what approach one should take then rather than Capybara? I didn't realise one needed a browser simulator at all since all I want to do is parse the document - ty

Answer (score 2):

Use `should have_xpath('//url')` instead. `have_selector` is for CSS.

See [the Capybara README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for more info.

Comment: Hi David. I still get the same problem with `response.should have_xpath('//url')` returns `expected xpath "//url" to return something`. In order to kick in Capybara I've even tried adding in the `:type => :request` tag to the test but it still fails

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the `have_selector` (or `have_xpath`) can only come from Webrat or Capybara. You're right in your comment to John that you don't need a browser simulator to test the API.

You may be invoking Webrat or Capybara by mistake as they use `visit` instead of `get` AFAIK. So the variables they match against may never have been populated by the page and so will always return false.

Rails should handle the XML document natively if the response content-type is correctly set to XML. Try using the `assert_tag` or `assert_content` test helper as a basic check.

I would just use Nokogiri to parse the XHTML and run normal RSpec tests against that:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)
xml.css("expression").size.should == 1
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks Andrew. I'll try that and tell you how it turns out